# Combine a .txt's name, and second interior string to create a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, batch-file, dictionary

I've written a batch script that is deployed to our network via Chocolatey and FOG that acquires the serial number of the machine and then ejects it via .txt in a file bearing the name of the PC that the serial number belongs to:

```
net use y: \\192.168.4.104\shared
wmic bio get serialnumber > Y:\IT\SSoftware\Serial_Numbers\%COMPUTERNAME%.txt
net use y: /delete
```

The folder Serial_Numbers is subsequently filled with .txts bearing the names of every computer on Campus.  With this in mind I'd like to write a Python script to go through and grab every .txt name and second interior string to form a dictionary, where you can call for the PC's name, and have the serial number returned.

I'm aware as to how I'd create the dictionary, and call from it, but I'm having troubles figuring out how to properly grab the .txt's name and second interior string, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Format of .txt documents:

```
SerialNumber
#############
```

Comment: `wmic bios get serialnumber /value|find "="` might make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>You can use [os.listdir](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.listdir) to list the directory files nad [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to filter them.</strike>

Use [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to list the files in your directory.

You can simply read the first line and stop using the file while populating the dictionary and you're done:

```
import glob
d = {}
# loop over '.txt' files only
for filename in glob.glob('/path_to_Serial_Numbers_folder/*.txt'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        file_name_no_extension = '.'.join(filename.split('.')[:-1])
        d[file_name_no_extension] = f.readline().strip()
print d
```

Comment: Why not just use [`glob.glob('/folder/path/*.txt')`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html?highlight=glob#glob.glob)?

Comment: @martineau , just a habit, changing it now, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import glob
data = {}
for fnm in glob.glob('*.txt'):
    data[fnm[:-4]] = open(fnm).readlines()[1].strip()
```

or, more succinctly

```
import glob
data = {f[:-4]:open(f).readlines()[1].strip() for f in glob.glob('*.txt')}
```

In the *dictionary comprehension* above,

- `f[:-4]` is the filename except the last four characters (i.e., ".txt"),
- `open(f).readlines()[1].strip()` is the second line of the file
  object and eventually
- `f` is an element of the list of filenames returned by `glob.glob()`.

Comment: I always forget about glob :)